# Why is my nodejs application with forever not starting with Upstart on EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, node.js, upstart

I am trying to start a nodejs application with `forever` (`forever` simply restarts the program if it crashes), but `forever` itself is not auto started on boot. So I am using upstart to initialize `forever`.

I have tried hundreds of ways to achieve this (many trial and error attempts), but nothing really seems to work for me. So my scenarios is:

- I am running an Amazon Linux Instance
- The app works great if running from command line (forever is working and upstart also)
- I am testing with `sudo start prv`

Here is the script I have so far (prv.conf, at `/etc/init/prv.conf`):

```
author "Renato Gama"
description "PRV"

start on runlevel [235]
stop on shutdown

respawn

export HOME="/home/ec2-user/prv/app"
exec su -c "/usr/bin/forever start -l forever.log -o /home/ec2-user/prv/logs/out.log -e /home/ec2-user/prv/logs/err.log --append /home/ec2-user/prv/app.js" root | logger -t PRV
```

IN FACT, from command line I can start the app by typing the following (and this works as expected):

```
cd /home/ec2-user/prv
sudo su -p (altough I am not using any specific env variable)
forever start -l f.log -o out.log -e err.log --append app.js
```

PS1 .: I haven't even tested on real boot as it doesn't even work with `sudo start prv`
PS2 .: If I visit the log it doesn't tell to much (exited normally). Part of the log is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/renatoargh/5302990)
PS3 .: After executing `sudo start prv` I got this

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-252-146-14 ~]$ sudo start prv
prv start/running, process 11477
```

But when I try to check if forever is running my proccess, it says:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-252-146-14 ~]$ sudo forever list
info:    No forever processes running
```

PS4.: My app binds to port `80` thats why I need a privileged user to run this.

EDIT: I am almost sure the problem is that I am getting EACCESS error on port 80

Comment: there is no reason to run the su in the upstart config since it will run as root anyway.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I cant get it to work even if I remove the `su` command, any clues?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in init(5), the export line is invalid (Upstart syntax is not shell). You need to specify:

```
env HOME="..."
export HOME
```

Please see:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#checking-how-a-service-might-react-when-run-as-a-job
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#see-the-environment-a-job-runs-in
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn

Also,

- remove respawn until your job works as you expect
- remove 'su'
- remove 'logger'

Finally,

Look in file `/var/log/upstart/yourjob.log` for job output.